# Display a progress bar page for a command line operation using INNOSETUP

Tags: command-line, inno-setup

Is there a possibility to link the operation running on a command line to the innosetup page ?

**Background :**
I have a huge.zip file that has to be extracted during install operation. To achieve this i send commands(commandline args) from the InnoSetup. The extraction process runs in the background i.e on the command prompt. But there is no way for an user to know whats actually happening.

**Required Solution** 
I would like to have some linking between these two parallel operations.
i.e somehow able to link the progress of the current operation (extraction of the files) from the command-line and display it to the user on the progress page during installation.
i.e i should be able to retrieve the remaining time / % operation completed to display it finally on the progress page.

I would greatly appreciate if anybody has any ideas for achieving the above

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really possible in Inno using a command line application as it (natively) has no way to read data from it.
You may have more luck creating a COM object that can fire events or make windows message callbacks that you then use to update the progress bar.

Comment: Can you suggest a better option if there's any ?

Comment: I already did, a COM/in process object/library that you can call and get feedback from.